# Using SPNEGO and LTPA in WebSphere

Tags: servlets, websphere, websphere-8, spnego, ltpa

General question. Server admin setup SPNEGO. The LTPA bullet is marked under Global Security in admin console. My understanding is that SPNEGO captures username from an initial sign-on (ie network). Later, if user goes to an app's URL, few of the many things happening is SPNEGO is going through user's ldap groups (admin console-securtity roles) trying to find group that is tied to app's role names. If match is found, user authorized and can go directly into app without having to use login form to enter credentials. But have problem trying to implement this. Checking `HttpServletRequest` - `getUserPrincipal().getName()` and `getRemoteUser()` at  front end of app are coming up `null`. If SPNEGO is in fact setup correctly, should a `null` ever be found?

Comment: You should provide us the related code as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a few things. SPNEGO is a mechanism to pass user authenticated in the Kerberos realm to the given service without need to pass user password. It has nothing to do with authorization - this part is done by WebSphere security service based on the id retrieved from the request (in short).

`Null` username usually is effect of not enabling Application Security in the server or not protecting application with Java EE security (security constraints defined in the `web.xml`).

For some basic information about SPNEGO in WebSphere, check the following page [Single sign-on for HTTP requests using SPNEGO web authentication](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/csec_SPNEGO_explain.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F2-8-2-31-2-5-0&lang=en)